Is the powerset monad unique?
The covariant powerset functor has a well-known monad structure, but is this monad structure unique? By the Yoneda lemma, there can be only two natural transformations $1 \Rightarrow \mathcal{P}$ and only one of those can work as the unit of a monad. But is the multiplication also unique?
As an aside: I remember being pretty surprised when I first learned that the powerset construction $X \mapsto \mathcal{P}(X)$ admits two functor structures, the covariant and the contravariant one. (For a while I even thought there was a third, sending $\mathcal{P}(f)(U)$ to $f[U']'$ where $-'$ is the complement. But luckily this one is isomorphic to the covariant one...)

Suppose that there exists another natural transformation $\mu'_X : \mathcal{P}^2(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(X)$ satisfying the monad laws. For any $U \in \mathcal{P}^2(X)$, we have:
$$\mu'_X({{x}}) = {x}, \quad \text{for all}\ x \in X.$$
For $U = {{x} | x \in A} $ with $A \subset X$,
$$ \mu'_X(U) = \mu'X({{x} | x \in A}) = \bigcup{x \in A} \mu'X({{x}}) = \bigcup{x \in A} {x} = A. $$
Lastly, for a general $U \in \mathcal{P}^2(X)$, we can express $U$ as a union of singletons and apply the same reasoning to conclude.

Not every family of sets consists of singletons. @Mechap

@Mechap why are you saying that $\mu'_X$ commutes with that union? In any case $\mu'_X({{x}\mid x\in A}) = A$ is just one of the monad laws, but it isn't clear how this helps in the general case.

You are right, $\eta_X(x) = \{x\}$ is forced, since $P(\eta_X)$ must be injective by the monad axioms, so $\eta_X(x) = \emptyset$ is not allowed. But for the multiplication there is a different choice, namely
$$\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) := \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \mathcal{T} \\ \bigcup \mathcal{T} & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{T} \end{cases}$$
for a family of subsets $\mathcal{T} \subseteq P(X)$. In words: we take the usual union if all the sets in the family are non-empty, otherwise just refuse to do anything and return the empty set. I suggest to call this the stubborn union.
Proof of the monad axioms
Naturality is obvious. The equations $\mu_X(P(\eta_X)(A)) = \mu_X(\{\{x\} : x \in A\}) = A$ and $\mu_X(\eta_{P(X)}(A)) = \mu_X(\{A\}) = A$ for $A \subseteq X$ are clear.
To prove associativity, let $\mathcal{R} \subseteq P^2(X)$ (this is a family of families of subsets). We compute
$$\begin{align*}
\mu_X(\mu_{P(X)}(\mathcal{R})) & = \begin{cases} \mu_X(\emptyset) & \emptyset \in \mathcal{R} \\ \mu_X(\bigcup \mathcal{R}) & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \end{cases} \\
& = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \mathcal{R} \\ \emptyset & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \text{ and } \emptyset \in \bigcup \mathcal{R} \\ \bigcup \bigcup \mathcal{R} & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \text{ and } \emptyset \notin \bigcup \mathcal{R} \end{cases}
\\
& = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \mathcal{R} \text{ or } \emptyset \in \bigcup \mathcal{R} \\ \bigcup \bigcup \mathcal{R} & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \text{ and }  \emptyset \notin \bigcup \mathcal{R} \end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
and
$$\begin{align*}
\mu_X(P(\mu_{X})(\mathcal{R})) &= \mu_X(\{\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) : \mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{R}\}) \\
& = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \{\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) : \mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{R}\}\\ \bigcup \{\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) : \mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{R}\} & \text{else} \end{cases} \\
& = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \mathcal{R} \text{ or } \emptyset \in \bigcup \mathcal{R}   \\ \bigcup \{\bigcup \mathcal{T} : \mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{R}\} & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \text{ and }  \emptyset \notin \bigcup \mathcal{R} \end{cases} \\
& = \begin{cases} \emptyset & \emptyset \in \mathcal{R} \text{ or } \emptyset \in \bigcup \mathcal{R} \\ \bigcup \bigcup \mathcal{R} & \emptyset \notin \mathcal{R} \text{ and }  \emptyset \notin \bigcup \mathcal{R}.\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$
Any hints if this monad already appears in the literature and if it has a name are appreciated.
Algebras for the monad
This raises of course the question how to describe the algebras for this monad. One can mimic the proof for the usual monad structure, where the algebras are sup-lattices, and arrive at those partially ordered sets where

every non-empty subset has a supremum,
there is a largest element.

For the lack of a better name (is there one?), let's call these twisted sup-lattices. For example, $]0,\infty]$ with the usual ordering is a twisted sup-lattice, but not a sup-lattice , since we don't have a smallest element (the supremum of the empty subset).
The free twisted sup-lattice on a set $X$ has underlying set $ P(X)$ but not with the usual ordering! For non-empty subsets it's the usual one, but we have $A \leq \emptyset$ for all $A$.
Classification of monad structures on $P$
Actually, the normal union and the "stubborn union" provide the only monad structures.
Theorem. There are exactly two monad structures on the functor $P : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$.
The proof is similar to the one in MO/479643 (where the domain of the natural transformation was $P^{\times n} = P \times \cdots \times P$, not $P^2 = P \circ P$). In fact, I have also used the name "stubborn union" for a certain operation $P \times P \to P$ there.
Let $\mu : P^2 \to P$ be a natural transformation such that $(P,\eta,\mu)$ is a monad. We already know $\eta_X(x) = \{x\}$. The monad axioms are $\mu_X(\{A\}) = A$ for $A \subseteq X$, $\mu_X(\{\{x\} : x \in A\}) = A$ for $A \subseteq X$, and associativitiy of $\mu$. Actually, we will not use associativity, it will follow!
Let $\mathcal{T} \subseteq P(X)$ be a family of sets. Consider the set $Y := \coprod_{A \in \mathcal{T}} A$ with the obvious map $p : Y \to X$ defined by extending the inclusions $A \hookrightarrow X$. We can also regard $\mathcal{T}$ as a family of disjoint subsets of $Y$, and naturality of $\mu$ with respect to $p$ yields $\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) = \mu_X(p(\mathcal{T})) = p( \mu_Y(\mathcal{T}))$. Therefore, in order to prove that $\mu$ is the union or the "stubborn union", it suffices to look at $Y$. Hence, we may assume $X = \coprod_{A \in \mathcal{T}} A$.
Then $\mu_X(\mathcal{T})$ is a subset of $X = \coprod_{A \in \mathcal{T}} A$, hence is of the form $\coprod_{A \in \mathcal{T}} A'$ for subsets $A' \subseteq A$. If $\sigma : A \to A$ is a permutation, we can extend it to $\sigma : X \to X$, and then naturality of $\mu$ with respect to $\sigma$ shows that $A'$ is invariant under $\sigma$. Hence, $A' = \emptyset$ or $A' = A$. Let us denote by $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ the set of those non-empty $A \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $A'=A$. Hence,
$$\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) = \coprod_{A \in \mathcal{T}'} A = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{T}'} A.$$
Notice that there is a canonical map
$$q : X \to \mathcal{T}, ~ x \mapsto A \text{ if } x \in A \in \mathcal{T}.$$
On the one hand, we have
$$q(\mu_X(\mathcal{T})) = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{T}'} q(A) = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{T}'} \{A\} = \mathcal{T}'.$$
On the other hand, by naturality we conclude
$$q(\mu_X(\mathcal{T})) = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(q(\mathcal{T})) = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(\{q(A) : A \in \mathcal{T}\}).$$
We have $q(A) = \{A\}$ for every non-empty $A \in \mathcal{T}$. Therefore, if $\emptyset \notin \mathcal{T}$, we conclude from the above calculations that $\mathcal{T}' = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(\{\{A\} : A \in \mathcal{T}\}) = \mathcal{T}$, and hence $\mu_{X}(\mathcal{T}) = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{T}} A$ is the normal union.
Now consider the "problematic" case $\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$, and let us write $\mathcal{T}^+ := \mathcal{T} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$. Our calculation above shows that
$$\mathcal{T}' = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\{A\} : A \in \mathcal{T}^+\}).$$
If $\mathcal{T} = \{\emptyset\}$, we get $\mathcal{T}' = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(\{\emptyset\}) = \emptyset$ and we are done. So assume that $\mathcal{T} \neq \{\emptyset\}$, i.e. $\mathcal{T}^+ \neq \emptyset$.
Now, there are two possible values for
$$W := \mu_{\{\star\}}(\{\emptyset, \{\star\}\}),$$
which is a subset of $\{\star\}$.
Case 1. We have $W = \emptyset$. We use the unique map $f : \mathcal{T} \to \{\star\}$. Then naturality of $\mu$ with respect to $f$ shows
$$f(\mathcal{T}') = \mu_{\{\star\}}(\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\{\star\} : A \in \mathcal{T}^+\}) = \mu_{\{\star\}}(\{\emptyset,\{\star\}\}) = W =  \emptyset,$$
hence $\mathcal{T}' = \emptyset$. This means $\mu_X(\mathcal{T}) = \emptyset$. Hence, $\mu$ is the "stubborn union".
Case 2. We have $W = \{\star\}$. Notice that $\mathcal{T}' = \mu_{\mathcal{T}}(\{\emptyset\} \cup \{\{A\} : A \in \mathcal{T}^+\})$ is a subset of $\mathcal{T}^+$ that is invariant under all permutations of $\mathcal{T}$ that fix the empty set, by naturality of $\mu$. Hence, it must be $\emptyset$ or $\mathcal{T}^+$. But if it was $\emptyset$, with $f$ as above we get $\emptyset = f(\mathcal{T}') = W = \{\star\}$, a contradiction. Hence, $\mathcal{T}' = \mathcal{T}^+$, meaning that $\mu$ is the normal union. $\checkmark$

PS: I know.

Funny, I would have expected there to be many more, similarly to the exotic monad structures on lists.

@NaïmFavier The reason that many things in that paper won't work is that they depend on the size of lists involved. The functorial action on lists doesn't change size, but the power set action can. In fact it can turn every inhabited set into a singleton using $! : X → 1$, which seems like would force a lot of behavior. Or–from another angle–depending on the (positive) size of a set is depending on its elements to some degree.

This should be something like the free pointed complete (except for the empty meet) semilattice? In the same way, the free semigroup with zero element gives a monad structure on lists that acts similarly.

So in a way, this monad models partial multivalued functions (which is different from multivalued functions possibly taking zero values).

This is amazing and unexpected! Thanks! I will now forever be able to pester people when they talk about "the" powerset monad :)

@Trebor Do you think there is a relation between this and a composition of the (usual) powerset monad with the maybe monad?

I have added now a proof that there exactly two monad structures on $P$.

Perhaps it's just me, but I don't find the uniqueness proof super clear. For instance, $μ_X(\mathcal{T}) = μ_Y(\mathcal{T})$ makes no literal sense, I think. $X$ and $Y$ needn't be isomorphic. I understand what needs to be inserted to the equation, but then one has to consider how that affects the subsequent argument. It also seems odd that we are considering $X$ to 'actually be' a coproduct over $\mathcal{T}$, which is the particular thing being flattened (and so, varies), but perhaps that is not a problem.

@DanDoel There was a typo. And it was short. I fixed it. Is it clearer now?

Here's another way of looking at it. The powerset functor can be expressed as the composition $1 + P_\text{ne}(-)$ of the failure/maybe/exception monad $1 + (-)$ and the non-empty powerset monad $P_\text{ne}$. A monad structure on this composition can be given by a distributive law $P_\text{ne}(1+X) \to 1+P_\text{ne}(X)$. I'm fairly sure that the usual monad arises when this map "fails" (i.e. returns $\ast$) only if all elements of the subset fail, while the stubborn one arises when this map fails if there exists at least one failure in the subset.
Are there only two distributive laws too?
